# Posting PHP with iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I am a beginner at with iOs and I am trying to post a value to a php page (the page handles the rest of the code).  However, in Xcode, the application crashes with this code (doesn't show any warnings or errors in the log or console though so im not sure whats going on).

Here is the code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/post.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"type=%@",typeofResponse.text];
 [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSError *err;
 [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
```

I'm trying to send 'typeofResponse.text' to php via a GET variable.  The php script then inserts it into a database.  However the 'type' always ends up being blank and the app crashes in the simulator with no logs.  What's wrong?

And yes, I know this is insecure, im doing this to get my feet wet with iOS.  Thanks!

Comment: first, did you check the *post before sending it, does it really contain anything before sending? Second, is your server's php is configured to get the "type" via GET or POST?

Comment: Yes, the data is in the variable 'typeofResponse.Text', from the debugger when it crashes, it has the correct variable.  Also the php script seems to be working, as when I run it manually (post.php?type=test) it does the expected behavior.

Comment: again, make sure your php is set to POST and not GET (when you run it as push.php?type=test, it is set to GET)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I made such a stupid error, yes it is working now - at least the php script is.  The application still crashes on the submit however with nothing in the console.  Thanks for the help with the amateur POST mistake.

Comment: what is the crash like? where does your debugger points on crash? and when?

Comment: Ok its not crashing however, it is pausing itself - I can still manually force it to continue by clicking "continue execution."  Does this indicate a crash or is it how XCode works? The above code is how the program should end, at least there is no further code to execute.

Comment: it indicates a crash, which line is it? (note the green bar at your right, containing the failure message)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17272/discussion-between-bartu-and-katherine-perotta)

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I see"